# 'min_move_x' for 'swipeleft' event in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

How do i use 'min_move_x' for 'swipeleft' event in jquery mobile?
Thats my code:

```
$("#summary_content").swipeleft( function() {


               $("#page").trigger('click');

           });


           $("#summary_content").swiperight( function() {


               $("#page").trigger('click');

               }
           });
```

Im trying that the swipe left function will work only if the user swipe 80% of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQM provides some event configuration items: http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/

For min_x, use `$.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold`

e.g.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){    
    $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = 100;    
    $("#summary_content").swipeleft( function() {
        alert('swipeleft');
        $("#page").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

This means you need to swipe horizontally at least 100px before the event is triggered.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/jmv7gg3c/)**

Play with the horizontalDistanceThreshold and then swipe left on the red box.

Comment: @anonicode, I think it only takes an integer number of pixels. For percent, you could do a calculation based on $(window).width * percentage/100 and update this on window resize and orientation change.

Comment: But it wont be dynemic, am i right? 
i need it dynamic, if the size of the window is change the min-swipe change to, thankes alot ! @ezanker

Comment: @anonicode, that's why I said to updated it on window resize and orientation change events.

Comment: thanks !! Id understend it @ezanker